# Installing extjs through wampserver

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, wampserver

I am trying to install extjs in the Apache directory of wampserver.

I download the Ext JS 4.2.1 from here:

```
    http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download/
```

I create a new folder named extjs in the directory:

```
   C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/htdocs/extjs/
```

I enable the wampserver and in the Chrome browser I type:

```
  http://localhost/extjs/index.html
```

Problem: And it gives:

```
  The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server
```

Does wampserver use different paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

It needs different path. Instead of apache the extjs file must be in: C:/wamp/www/lib/extjs

And than typing in the browser:

```
http://localhost/lib/extjs/index.html
```

It works.

The answer came from: http://www.objis.com/formation-java/tutoriel-ajax-extjs.html#partie2